# python data frame - removing unwanted unicode rows

Tags: python, pandas, unicode

I have a column "name" in a data frame.
I want to drop all the rows, that it's names  not in names_all:

```
names_all = ['alice', 'bob', 'david']
```

all the strings in names_all and the data frame is a unicode string.

I wrote the code:

```
for index, row in history.iterrows():
    if row['name'] not in names_all:
        history.drop(index, inplace=True)
```

But for some reason, it is doing weird stuff. It is dropping too many rows (dropped all the 1700 first rows and some more).
Before I encoded all the string to unicode, it did some weird stuff too, but not in that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just select those that match `names_all`:

```
history = history.loc[history.name.isin(names_all)]
```

Comment: Seems to me like he wanted to drop rows that are not in list, his code uses `not in`

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:**

```
history = history[history['name'].isin(names_all)]
```

**Solution 2:**

```
history = history.query("name in @names_all"]
```

Comment: I don't know this approach, but it doesn't work. It messes the whole data frame.

Comment: @sheldonzy, sorry, i misunderstood your question. Please check it now...